# How to build a Plinko board of words from a dictionary better than brute force?

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider the following arrangement of letters:

```
    B
   O A
  N R I
 D E N T
```

Start at the top letter and choose one of the two letters below, Plinko-style, until you reach the bottom. No matter what path you choose you create a four-letter word: BOND, BONE, BORE, BORN, BARE, BARN, BAIN, or BAIT. The fact that DENT reads across the bottom is just a nice coincidence.

I'd like help figuring out an algorithm that can design such a layout, where each possible path from the top to the bottom generates a distinct word from a (provided) dictionary. The inputs to the program would be a starting letter (B, in this example) and a word length n (4, in this example). It would return either the letters that make up such a layout, or a message saying that it's not possible. It doesn't have to be deterministic, so it could possibly generate different layouts with the same input.

I haven't thought of anything better than a brute-force approach so far. That is, for all `26^[(n+2)(n-1)/2]` ways of choosing letters for the bottom part of the layout, to check if all possible `2^(n-1)` paths give words that are in the dictionary. I considered some sort of prefix-tree, but the fact that paths can cross and share letters messed with me. I'm most comfortable in Python, but at minimum I'd just like the idea for an algorithm or approach that would work for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What's a `BAIN`?

Comment: Of course you need to add also that the words must be distinct, otherwise just repeating the same word would fit your description (e.g. F, II, NNN, EEEE: whathever path you choose the word is "FINE")

Comment: @CJ59 Dialect word meaning (1) ready, willing, inclined (2) short, near.

Comment: @6502 Good point about distinct words. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Please describe the algorithm you've considered as "brute force."

Comment: For all 26^[(n+2)(n-1)/2] ways of choosing letters for the bottom part of the layout, check to see if all possible 2^(n-1) paths give words that are in the dictionary.

Comment: By the way, I waited for several minutes for an answer from the [program](https://gist.github.com/6502/26552858e93ce4d4ec3a8ef46100df79) by by 6502, who wrote the accepted anser, for [ENGLISH - 194,000 words](http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm) with `b 5` (764 acceptable words. Interestingly, it output a solution for b 4 very fast), until I finally interrupted it. My program below output a solution in 55 seconds. (I'm using top of the line MacBook pro)

Comment: (FYI I edited the question slightly to try and prevent it from closing while it was on hold.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this a quite interesting problem.

The first attempt was a random solver; in other words it just fills the triangle with letters and then counts how many "errors" are present (words not in the dictionary). Then a hill-climbing is performed by changing a one or more letter randomly and seeing if the error improves; if the error remains the same the changes are still accepted (so making a random-walk on plateau areas).

Amazingly enough this can solve in reasonable time non-obvious problems like 5-letter words starting with 'b':

```
    b
   a u
  l n r
 l d g s
o y s a e
```

I then tried a full-search approach to be able to answer also "no-solution" part and the idea was to write a recursive search:

## First step

Just write down all acceptable words on the left side; e.g.

```
    b
   a ?
  l ? ?
 l ? ? ?
o ? ? ? ?
```

and call recursively until we find an acceptable solution or fail

## Step 2

Write down all acceptable words on the right side if the second letter is
greater than the second letter of the first word, e.g.

```
    b
   a u
  l ? r
 l ? ? k
o ? ? ? e
```

This is done to avoid searching symmetric solutions (for any given solution another one can be obtained by simply mirroring on the X axis)

## Other steps

In the general case the first question mark is replaced with all letters in the alphabet if for all words that use the chosen question mark either

1. the word has no question marks and is in the dictionary, or
2. there are words in the dictionary that are compatible (all characters except question marks are a match)

If no solution is found for the specific question mark chosen there's no point in keeping searching so `False` is returned. Probably using some heuristics for choosing which question mark for fill first would speed up search, I didn't investigate that possibility.

For the case 2 (searching if there are compatible words) I am creating `26*(N-1)` sets of words that have a prescribed character in a certain position (position 1 is not considered) and I'm using set intersection on all non-question-mark characters.

This approach is able to tell in about 30 seconds (PyPy) that there are no solution for 5-letter words starting with `w` (there are 468 words in the dictionary with that starting letter).

The code for this implementation can be seen at

https://gist.github.com/6502/26552858e93ce4d4ec3a8ef46100df79

(the program expects a file named `words_alpha.txt` containing all valid words and then must be called specifiying the initial letter and the size;
as dictionary I used the file from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I didn't see your solution but even after reading it I don't understand your approach. Suppose you have length 3 and that the list of words starting with A is ABD, ABE, ACG, ACF. What is a "full binary subtree"? With these words there is no solution, but there is a solution if you replace ACG with ACE (the solution is A/BC/DEF)... the trie *structure* is identical. The letter E in the middle is used by two words (the "cross and share" problem); there is no solution if you place the word ABE on the left of the diagram... but another valid solution is A/CB/FED (the symmetric one).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I misunderstood the problem. Now I see the issue of shared letters on any given level. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing the ideas behind your approach as well as some working code. This will give me a great launching point for trying something on my own.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the file with the 468 words you used in testing (words_alpha.txt)? I'd like to try it with my code :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added a reference to the dictionary used

Comment: Thanks! By the way, it's been several minutes and I'm still waiting for your program to output an answer for [ENGLISH - 194,000 words](http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm) with `b 5` (764 acceptable words. Interestingly, it output a solution for `b 4` very fast). My program output a solution in 55 seconds. (cc @jamisans) (I'm using top of the line MacBook pro)

Comment: I like the idea of the random walker.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you but could you please confirm my experience with the program in your gist that you linked to? It seems to take more than a few minutes for the parameters I described in my above comment (`b 5` with the linked English dictionary; I didn't wait to see if it ends). Could it be something I did wrong or maybe a bug, or is it expected behaviour with the current code in the gist?

Comment: @גלעדברקן No trouble... I found the time to try to run your program (no time to try to understand it however) and observed that in most cases I checked is 5-10 times faster when answering negatively. I'm really busy right now and I don't have time to investigate more (neither your code or mine) but probably I will in the future...

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't asking about negatively. I could not get any answer from your program for the parameters and data I described in my comment - I wanted to understand why. (My program answered in 55 seconds.) With that same dictionary, my program output a negative result for `b 5` given the first 468 words (out of 764) in 24 seconds. (My program is more a proof of concept. The implementation results in slightly stricter rules for the Plinko board.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן: my program indeed is not searching all valid solutions; the problem is that if you forbid repeated letters on horizontal lines in the triangle you're also forbidding some valid solutions (e.g. in `A`/`BC`/`DED` the words are `ABD`, `ABE`, `ACE`, `ACD` and there are no repetitions, but the last line has two letters `D`). Like I said I'm however VERY busy right now, on an even more interesting and less artificial optimization problem for which however I'm being paid real money to solve (not reputation points :-) ). This is still interesting and probably I'll get to it later.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. (Regarding repetitions, I'm not sure if you were referring to mine or yours but that's ok. Mine currently has a case logging "TODO" for horizontal repeated letters, but it doesn't matter to prove the idea...). Have success with the real money problem. Working on problems here are sometimes a nice respite for me from those that pay, ha ha :)

Answer (score 6):

Pretend the `V W X Y Z` on the bottom here actually complete words.

```
    B
   A O
  I R N
 T N E D
V W X Y Z
```

We can implement a backtracking search with heuristics so strict, it seems unlikely any wrong path would go very far.

Insert all the `n` sized words that begin with the same letter in a simple tree as below. Now perform a depth first search, asserting the following: each successive level needs one additional "shared" letter, meaning `p(letter)` instances of it on that level, with the additional requirement that their two children are the same letters (e.g., the two `R`s in parentheses on level 2 could be a "shared" letter because their children are the same).

What is `p(letter)`? Pascal's triangle of course! `n choose r` is exactly the number of instances of the letter needed on the relevant level of this simple tree, according to the Plinko board. On level 3, if we've chosen `R` and `R`, we'll need 3 `N`s and 3 `E`s to express the "shared" letters on that level. And each of the 3 `N`s must have the same children letters (W,X in this case), and each of the 3 `E`s must also (X,Y).

```
                     B
            /                 \
          A                     O
      /       \             /       \   
     I        (R)         (R)        N
    / \       / \         / \       / \
   T  (N)   (N)  E      (N)  E     E   D
  V W W X   W X X Y     W X X Y   X Y Y Z

4 W's, 6 X's, 4 Y's
```

#### UPDATE

Out of curiosity, here's some [Python code](https://repl.it/repls/DecimalTwinPolygon) :)

```py
from itertools import combinations
from copy import deepcopy

# assumes words all start
# with the same letter and
# are of the same length
def insert(word, i, tree):
  if i == len(word):
    return
  if word[i] in tree:
    insert(word, i + 1, tree[word[i]])
  else:
    tree[word[i]] = {}
    insert(word, i + 1, tree[word[i]])

# Pascal's triangle
def get_next_needed(needed):
  next_needed = [[1, None, 0]] + [None] * (len(needed) - 1) + [[1, None, 0]]

  for i, _ in enumerate(needed):
    if i == len(needed) - 1:
      next_needed[i + 1] = [1, None, 0]
    else:
      next_needed[i + 1] = [needed[i][0] + needed[i+1][0], None, 0]
  return next_needed

def get_candidates(next_needed, chosen, parents):
  global log
  if log:
    print "get_candidates: parents: %s" % parents
  # For each chosen node we need two children.
  # The corners have only one shared node, while
  # the others in each group are identical AND
  # must have all have a pair of children identical
  # to the others' in the group. Additionally, the
  # share sequence matches at the ends of each group.
  #    I       (R)     (R)      N
  #   / \      / \     / \     / \
  #  T  (N)  (N)  E  (N)  E   E   D

  # Iterate over the parents, choosing
  # two nodes for each one
  def g(cs, s, seq, i, h):
    if log:
      print "cs, seq, s, i, h: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (cs, s, seq, i, h)

    # Base case, we've achieved a candidate sequence
    if i == len(parents):
      return [(cs, s, seq)]
    # The left character in the corner is
    # arbitrary; the next one, shared.
    # Left corner:
    if i == 0:
      candidates = []
      for (l, r) in combinations(chosen[0].keys(), 2):
        _cs = deepcopy(cs)
        _cs[0] = [1, l, 1]
        _cs[1][1] = r
        _cs[1][2] = 1
        _s = s[:]
        _s.extend([chosen[0][l], chosen[0][r]])
        _h = deepcopy(h)
        # save the indexes in cs of the
        # nodes chosen for the parent 
        _h[parents[1]] = [1, 2]
        candidates.extend(g(_cs, _s, l+r, 1, _h))
        _cs = deepcopy(cs)
        _cs[0] = [1, r, 1]
        _cs[1][1] = l
        _cs[1][2] = 1
        _s = s[:]
        _s.extend([chosen[0][r], chosen[0][l]])
        _h = deepcopy(h)
        # save the indexes in cs of the
        # nodes chosen for the parent
        _h[parents[1]] = [1, 2]
        candidates.extend(g(_cs, _s, r+l, 1, _h))
      if log:
        print "returning candidates: %s" % candidates
      return candidates
    # The right character is arbitrary but the
    # character before it must match the previous one.
    if i == len(parents)-1:
      l = cs[len(cs)-2][1]
      if log:
        print "rightmost_char: %s" % l
      if len(chosen[i]) < 2 or (not l in chosen[i]):
        if log:
          print "match not found: len(chosen[i]) < 2 or (not l in chosen[i])"
        return []
      else:
        result = []
        for r in [x for x in chosen[i].keys() if x != l]:
          _cs = deepcopy(cs)
          _cs[len(cs)-2][2] = _cs[len(cs)-2][2] + 1
          _cs[len(cs)-1] = [1, r, 1]
          _s = s[:] + [chosen[i][l], chosen[i][r]]
          result.append((_cs, _s, seq + l + r))
        return result

    parent = parents[i]
    if log:
      print "get_candidates: g: parent, i: %s, %s" % (parent, i)
    _h = deepcopy(h)
    if not parent in _h:
      prev = _h[parents[i-1]]
      _h[parent] = [prev[0] + 1, prev[1] + 1]
    # parent left and right children
    pl, pr = _h[parent]
    if log:
      print "pl, pr: %s, %s" % (pl, pr)
    l = cs[pl][1]
    if log:
      print "rightmost_char: %s" % l
    if len(chosen[i]) < 2 or (not l in chosen[i]):
      if log:
        print "match not found: len(chosen[i]) < 2 or (not l in chosen[i])"
      return []
    else:
      # "Base case," parent nodes have been filled
      # so this is a duplicate character on the same
      # row, which needs a new assignment
      if cs[pl][0] == cs[pl][2] and cs[pr][0] == cs[pr][2]:
        if log:
          print "TODO"
        return []
      # Case 2, right child is not assigned
      if not cs[pr][1]:
        candidates = []
        for r in [x for x in chosen[i].keys() if x != l]:
          _cs = deepcopy(cs)
          _cs[pl][2] += 1
          _cs[pr][1] = r
          _cs[pr][2] = 1
          _s = s[:]
          _s.extend([chosen[i][l], chosen[i][r]])
          # save the indexes in cs of the
          # nodes chosen for the parent
          candidates.extend(g(_cs, _s, seq+l+r, i+1, _h))
        return candidates
      # Case 3, right child is already assigned
      elif cs[pr][1]:
        r = cs[pr][1]
        if not r in chosen[i]:
          if log:
            print "match not found: r ('%s') not in chosen[i]" % r
          return []
        else:
          _cs = deepcopy(cs)
          _cs[pl][2] += 1
          _cs[pr][2] += 1
          _s = s[:]
          _s.extend([chosen[i][l], chosen[i][r]])
          # save the indexes in cs of the
          # nodes chosen for the parent
          return g(_cs, _s, seq+l+r, i+1, _h)
    # Otherwise, fail 
    return []

  return g(next_needed, [], "", 0, {})

def f(words, n):
  global log
  tree = {}
  for w in words:
    insert(w, 0, tree)

  stack = []
  root = tree[words[0][0]]
  head = words[0][0]
  for (l, r) in combinations(root.keys(), 2):
    # (shared-chars-needed, chosen-nodes, board)
    stack.append(([[1, None, 0],[1, None, 0]], [root[l], root[r]], [head, l + r], [head, l + r]))

  while stack:
    needed, chosen, seqs, board = stack.pop()
    if log:
      print "chosen: %s" % chosen
      print "board: %s" % board
    # Return early for demonstration
    if len(board) == n:
      # [y for x in chosen for y in x[1]]
      return board

    next_needed = get_next_needed(needed)
    candidates = get_candidates(next_needed, chosen, seqs[-1])
    for cs, s, seq in candidates:
      if log:
        print "  cs: %s" % cs
        print "  s: %s" % s
        print "  seq: %s" % seq
      _board = board[:]
      _board.append("".join([x[1] for x in cs]))
      _seqs = seqs[:]
      _seqs.append(seq)
      stack.append((cs, s, _seqs, _board))

"""
    B
   A O
  I R N
 T N E D
Z Y X W V
"""
words = [
  "BONDV",
  "BONDW",
  "BONEW",
  "BONEX",
  "BOREW",
  "BOREX",
  "BAREW",
  "BAREX",
  "BORNX",
  "BORNY",
  "BARNX",
  "BARNY",
  "BAINX",
  "BAINY",
  "BAITY",
  "BAITZ"]
N = 5
log = True

import time
start_time = time.time()
solution = f(list(words), N)
print ""
print ""
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print "solution: %s" % solution
print ""
if solution:
  for i, row in enumerate(solution):
    print " " * (N - 1 - i) + " ".join(row)
  print ""
print "words: %s" % words
```